# What is the meaning and function of だというのか?

Tags: rhetorical-questions

> じゃあ③が正解**だってのか**よッ！

I know the bold part is jut a shortened version of だというのか. But what is the meaning and function of だというのか? Is it just used to form an exclamation and it means nothing?

Comment: Does this link make sense in your context? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/24856/the-usage-of-%e3%81%a8%e3%81%84%e3%81%86-in-questions/24858#24858

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The usage of という in questions](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/24856/the-usage-of-%e3%81%a8%e3%81%84%e3%81%86-in-questions)

Answer (score 0):

「The link posted gives us that だというのか mean

> 「～～というのだ」、「～～というの」、「～～というのか」, etc. added at the end of a question
> generally functions to emphasize the question itself.
>
> By adding one of those phrases, you are expressing the fact that you
> really want to know the answer because whatever happened that caused
> you to ask the question perplexes, surprises, shocks you, etc.

So I would translate as :

> Is it really true ?

Comment: Why not simply translate as 'So, are you saying 3 is the right answer!?', where the '!?'  perhaps conveys the sense of かよッ?