# How do you use "iuno/いうの"？

Tags: grammar, definitions

I've seen this word a couple of times and am currently stuck on how to use it..

I know "いう" means "say" but I don't understand the の particle attached to it. Could someone provide a couple of examples of how to use this? The only example I could find online was

"**それ は えいご では なんと いうの ですか**." which I assume "**なんというの**" translates to "how do you say"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The usage of という in questions](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/24856/the-usage-of-%e3%81%a8%e3%81%84%e3%81%86-in-questions)

Comment: Well, that gives me another example of how it can be used, but I'm still not exactly sure what the の is doing there, could you give me an explanation of this? So what I'm getting from the example you provided was that it "何があったというのだ" would basically translate to "what the heck just happened" with "いうの" being the "what the heck" since it emphasizes what was just said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding の after a verb is a way of forming a noun clause. Adding the ですか then turns it into a question in the polite form. Ending with the の like in your second example is the same but in a casual form.

Note that in this case という is being used quite literally, asking "how do you say that." But という is an idiom that can be used in other ways as well.