# というのか vs というのですか

Tags: word-choice

> 「精霊がアイドル......しかも最低でも半年以上前からこっちの世界に溶け込んで生活してた**っていうの**？こんな活動をしながら？はっ、狂三なんて目じゃないわね」
>
> 琴里が発した狂三の名に、士道はぴくりと顔を動かした。以前、人間として士道のクラスに転入してきた精霊である。

I previously thought the bold part is the same as というのか until I have been told it is a causal version of というのですか today. So is there any difference between というのか and というのですか?

Answer (score 0):

~~ というのですか means something like "'are you saying?' or 'so you're saying'. It's certainly a rhetorical question, not a real one. This form is often in response to someone who has provided surprising information, but it can also be used when realizing something for yourself."

See the answer provided in the [link](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/24856/the-usage-of-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86-in-questions/24858#24858):

> 「～～というのだ」、「～～というの」、「～～というのか」, etc. added at the end of a question
> generally functions to emphasize the question itself.
>
> By adding one of those phrases, you are expressing the fact that you
> really want to know the answer because whatever happened that caused
> you to ask the question perplexes, surprises, shocks you, etc.

~~というのか is more about rephrasing what has been told before, something like "I said this, but it indeed means that", "or how should I say it". It is used to nuance what you just said.
it is similar to と言うより