# What would be the difference between というのであれば and であれば?

Tags: grammar

> 1.放課後。一度帰路に就いた折紙は一人、来禅高校へと戻ってきていた。
>
> 理由は一つ。下校している途中、いつもつけている髪飾りがなくなっていることに気ついたのである。
>
> 別に小さなピン一つ、なくしたところでさしたる痛手にはならないのだがーーそれは昔母に買ってもらったものである**というのであれば**話は別だった。
>
> 2.まあ普通の女の子が対象、**というのであれば**間違いなくそちらが正解だ。

Hi. Could you help me understand the expression というのであれば? It seems we can just say ものであれば and 対象であれば respectively in those texts. What would be difference between というのであれば and であれば?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

というのであれば is a (stiff) conditional form of というのだ, which is と言う followed by an explanatory-の. In many cases, you can simply understood というのだ as "it is that one says ～". But when it is followed by から, (で)は, (で)あれば, か, etc., the literal meaning of 言う is often lost and the phrase works as an emphatic reason marker. See also: [The usage of という in questions](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24856/5010)

In your first example, それは昔母に買ってもらったものであるというのであれば literally means "if it is that *she says* it is something her mother bought to her long ago", but you can treat this as an emphatic version of 'if'.

Your second example doesn't have enough context, but doesn't "if you say" or "if one says" make sense?

Comment: Thank you very much. I see. The context of the second example is that the protagonist was dating his classmate 折紙. They were supposed to watch a movie, which was common for couples. But instead they went to a drug store since 折紙 was not an ordinary girl.

Comment: And I have some further questions. Could you help me with them? 
1. Does というのなら have the same nuance and function as というのであれば?

Comment: 2. Since (I was told by native speakers that) のであれば can be subjunctive, is というのであれば also subjunctive mood? 3. Can the というのだ be the same as ということだ, which is used to introduce some conclusion or give some summary? Sorry if I have asked too much.

Comment: @chinoalpha 1. Yes なら and であれば are interchangeable when they follow a noun (the latter is stiffer). 2. I'm not sure how 'subjunctive mood' is used in Japanese grammar... We don't have a special construction like "if I *were* you". 3. In your examples, yes, というのであれば, というのなら, ということであれば and ということなら are all interchangeable.

Comment: Thank you again. And would it be unnatural if we use ものであれば and 対象であれば respectively in those examples? And are there any cases where というのだ and ということだ have different nuances?